# How should we use ScanWiFi() in Brightscript to display an array of wifi networks available?

Tags: brightscript

How should we use ScanWiFi() in Brightscript to display an array of wifi networks available?
I need to display the list of available wifi networks obtained from brightscript in my Ui using javascript.

I tried

```
x = CreateObject("roNetworkConfiguration", "wlan0")
x.ScanWiFi()

Print x
```

I got an error as 'invalid'

Comment: Yes, I am developing for BrightSign. How should I scan for devices in BrightSign?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting print as "invalid", because `ScanWiFi()` returns an Array of wifi's which you have to store in a variable. Its not a setter method.

Please use below code.

```
x = CreateObject("roNetworkConfiguration", "wlan0")

wifiList = x.ScanWiFi()

print"WiFiList: "wifiList
```